# GIT: Wordpress 3rd party plugin as git submodule

Tags: wordpress, git, github

I have my full wordpress installation as a git repository.

I have one plugin that's created by 3rd party company. Said company also provides so called addons for its plugin. When those addons are installed( through regular wordpress plugin add functionality ), it doesn't just copy files, but actually initializes git repositories for each plugin addon that's installed.

It's important to note that I don't have access to those repositories myself, so I can't just clone them. Another thing that's crucial is that some of those addons will be checked out so that they use different branches - in some cases it's master, in others it's '1_0_3', so there's no way to predict which addon will checkout which branch.

So, when I now do `git status`, I can see those directories as not  tracked. If I do `git add my-plugin`, then I get a git hint/warning that this directory is already a git repo. Also, when I'm updating those addons, again through regular wordpress means, plugin updater, it's going to git pull new code, and perhaps switch branch.

So, given the plugin is updating/adding it's own git repo, and is using git for updates, should I use git submodule, or just git add?

If I use git submodule, how will that work with plugins way of updating git itself? Note that some plugins are checking out main/master branch, while others may be using tag branches, or release branches( ie. not main nor master ).

Comment: Why would you have the whole installation as a git repo? You should only have whatever piece of content you are working on (theme, plugin...) as a git repo

Comment: How does that at all relate to the question? The situation is as it is, and I'm asking a question based on what the current situation is. You could've as easily ask "Why use WordPress", or why use "git" for that matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update

Below, is a new answer based on comments and updates to the question.

### TL;DR:

1. Delete the plugin Git files.
2. Use `git add` at the WordPress installation root.
3. Use the WordPress [upgrader_process_complete](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/upgrader_process_complete/) action hook to execute a shell script that deletes plugin Git files each time WordPress updates the plugin.

---

### The conflict

A WordPress plugin that includes its own Git files is in conflict with the super-project (root WordPress installation) Git repository.

### Git is not used for WordPress updates

The question says:

> when I'm updating those addons, again through regular wordpress means, plugin updater, **it's going to git pull new code** (emphasis mine), and perhaps switch branch.

> So, given the plugin is updating/adding it's own git repo, and **is using git for updates**...  (emphasis mine)

The WordPress plugin updater only downloads plugins from the WordPress.org Plugin Directory.

The [WordPress Developer note](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2021/06/29/introducing-update-uri-plugin-header-in-wordpress-5-8/) about the Plugin Header `Update URI` says:

> If the value of this new field [`Update URI`] matches any URI other than `https://wordpress.org/plugins/{$slug}/` or `w.org/plugin/{$slug}`, WordPress will not attempt to update [the plugin].

WordPress.org offers a plugin hosting service. Their [requirements](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-org/#requirements) for plugins state:

> The provided Subversion repository must be used for functional WordPress plugins only.

The requirement to use **Subversion** means that WordPress plugin updates do not use Git. However, Git updates could be possible due to things like custom post-update behavior triggered by the plugin, post-update steps required of the WordPress administrator, or a non-conventional WordPress installation.

Unless the question is updated with details to confirm that the third-party plugin makes active use of Git (or Git files) in the host system using the plugin, it can be assumed that plugin Git files can be deleted without consequence. The third party is likely using Git for development, and (as [recommended by WordPress](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-org/detailed-plugin-guidelines/#14-frequent-commits-to-a-plugin-should-be-avoided)) using Subversion for releases. The `.git` folder and associated files could simply be among the files and folders checked into Subversion, and are not required in the `wp-content/plugins/` folder for the plugin to work.

### Use `git add`

Assuming it is safe to delete the plugin Git files, use `git add` at the super-project level to add the root plugin folder to the super-project repository.

### Automatic plugin updates

If WordPress automatic updates are permitted for the plugin, newly downloaded files will re-introduce Git files to the root plugin folder, conflicting with the super-project.

If Git-tracking the root WordPress installation must continue, then manual action must be taken by removing Git files every time the plugin is updated.

...*Unless*

the WordPress [upgrader_process_complete](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/upgrader_process_complete/) action hook is used. This hook fires when the upgrader process is complete. This means after a plugin update, the hook fires, and the list of updated plugins can be retrieved. If that third-party plugin were updated, a shell script could be triggered to automatically delete the `.git` folder and associated files.

Comment: The problem with what you wrote is that I don't really have access to those 3rd party repositories, so I can't really clone those on my own. Another thing is that I don't want to be updating it manually, for reasons described in the question. 3rd party plugins may or may not use main/master branch, and there's no way for me to know that.

Comment: You say: *some plugins, when installed, are initialised as git repositories.* Then you say: *I don't really have access to those 3rd party repositories*. Could you please update your question with an explanation of how these plugins are installed if you do not have access to them? Sorry, I did not see in your question that you do not want to update the plugin local repository manually. What I read is that the remote branch might not be trunk/main. This is why my answer demonstrates how to use a submodule with a non-main remote branch. Perhaps more detail in your question will help.

Comment: Sorry about that kofeigen, my bad. I have just edited the question.

Comment: When you say the plugin: *actually initializes git repositories for each plugin addon* it suggests the plugin is running `git init` shell commands on the host system. Are you sure the plugin activation process is running git commands? Or is a `.git` folder just among the files downloaded and installed into the `wp-content/plugins/...` directory? If neither you nor the addon is running git commands for those plugin directories, why would you need to track the branch/tag they use? The branches/tags used would have already been decided by the 3rd party and reflected in the WP Plugin download.

Comment: @errorous Hi. I updated my answer. Please let me know if it fits your use case.

Comment: this is perfect, thanks. Sorry for the belated comment!